# Gulp multiple src

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am trying to inject a concatenated css file into my index.html using 'gulp-inject' and then version my files.  I can get this working separately but what I am trying to do is compile everything in a single task so that I can run assetVersion() against certain files and the index.html.  The problem I have is that my 'styles.min.css' is not written to disk and I'm not sure how to combine the streams to achieve my goal.  Can anyone help?

```
gulp.task('compile',['clean'],function() { 

    // CSS - minify, concat to one file and copy
    gulp.src(paths.css + '*', { base: paths.base })
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + paths.css));

    // Images - minify and copy
    gulp.src(paths.images + '*', { base: paths.base })
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));

    // Index.html - inject the concatenated css, asset version and copy to dist
    gulp.src(paths.index)
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(paths.dist + paths.css + 'styles.min.css', {read: false})))
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(assetVersion())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist)); 

});
```

Comment: The styles.min.css is not being written to disk?  What is your paths.dist and paths.css?  And you probably want gulp.src(paths.css + '**/*.css, ...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) to force run each task synchronously.

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence')

gulp.task('compile', ['clean'], function() {
    return runSequence(['compile:css', 'compile:images'], 'compile:version');
});

gulp.task('compile:css', function() {

    // CSS - minify, concat to one file and copy
    return gulp.src(paths.css + '*', { base: paths.base })
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + paths.css));
});

gulp.task('compile:images', function() {
    // Images - minify and copy
    return gulp.src(paths.images + '*', { base: paths.base })
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});

gulp.task('compile:version', function() {
    // Index.html - inject the concatenated css, asset version and copy to dist
    return gulp.src(paths.index)
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(paths.dist + paths.css + 'styles.min.css', { read: false })))
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(assetVersion())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just trying to carry out all the tasks on the source before moving to dist/ but I can inject/version on the dist/index.html I guess